How to do script actions before a Tailwind PrimeVue v3 Stepper panel change
I'm trying to use the Tailwind PrimeVue v3 Stepper component and I need to perform some actions before moving between each StepperPanel.
For example, I want to perform a simple console.log("before panel change") from inside the <script setup lang='ts'> area before each panel changes.
How can that be done?
From the docs I can see that the PrimeVue Stepper component has update:activeStep and step-change emits but those are triggered after the panels change. And I need to do the script actions before the panel changes.
The docs also show the use of prevCallback and nextCallback for moving between panels, so I assume I need to hook into those somehow. But those are provided inside the template and I have no idea how to access them inside the script tag area.
Here is a live URL to try with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-k97nc8?file=app.vue
<template>
  <div class="card flex justify-center">
    <Stepper>
      <StepperPanel header="Header I">
        <template #content="{ nextCallback }">
          <div class="flex flex-col h-[12rem]">
            <div
              class="border-2 border-dashed border-surface-200 dark:border-surface-700 rounded-md bg-surface-0 dark:bg-surface-950 flex-auto flex justify-center items-center font-medium"
            >
              Content I
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex pt-4 justify-end">
            <Button
              label="Next"
              icon="pi pi-arrow-right"
              iconPos="right"
              @click="nextCallback"
            />
          </div>
        </template>
      </StepperPanel>
      <StepperPanel header="Header II">
        <template #content="{ prevCallback, nextCallback }">
          <div class="flex flex-col h-[12rem]">
            <div
              class="border-2 border-dashed border-surface-200 dark:border-surface-700 rounded-md bg-surface-0 dark:bg-surface-950 flex-auto flex justify-center items-center font-medium"
            >
              Content II
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex pt-4 justify-between">
            <Button
              label="Back"
              severity="secondary"
              icon="pi pi-arrow-left"
              @click="prevCallback"
            />
            <Button
              label="Next"
              icon="pi pi-arrow-right"
              iconPos="right"
              @click="nextCallback"
            />
          </div>
        </template>
      </StepperPanel>
      <StepperPanel header="Header III">
        <template #content="{ prevCallback }">
          <div class="flex flex-col h-[12rem]">
            <div
              class="border-2 border-dashed border-surface-200 dark:border-surface-700 rounded-md bg-surface-0 dark:bg-surface-950 flex-auto flex justify-center items-center font-medium"
            >
              Content III
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex pt-4 justify-start">
            <Button
              label="Back"
              severity="secondary"
              icon="pi pi-arrow-left"
              @click="prevCallback"
            />
          </div>
        </template>
      </StepperPanel>
    </Stepper>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// Do something in here BEFORE moving between stepper panels
// For example, do a console.log("before panel change")
// I assume I need to use nextCallback and prevCallback from the template
// But I don't know how to access those callbacks here inside script
</script>

<style scoped>
.p-stepper {
  flex-basis: 50rem;
}
</style>


This is reasonably common situation, and a possible implication for such a requirement could be that an action is asynchronous; this couldn't be handled with Stepper events because Vue events don't have a mechanism to wait for asynchronous side effect in event handlers.
Third-party libraries aren't generally expected to cover this range of requirements, they need to provide enough flexibility through callbacks; this what Stepper already did here. Since step action is triggered in the same component "before" action needs to be performed, a developer has full control over their execution:
<template #content="{ nextCallback }">
    ...
    <Button
      @click="changeStep($event, nextCallback)"
    />
  </div>
  ...

<script setup lang="ts">
function changeStep(event: MouseEvent, callback: (event: Event) => void) {
  // Do some actions
  callback(event);
}
</script>

Notice that original mouse event is passed as is in case the implementation depends on it.

Thanks, this works. For others using TypeScript you can type the args as such event: MouseEvent, callback: (event: Event) => void. Maybe you will also want to update your answer with these.

You're welcome. Sure, especially since this is TS question
